# Giving a second initial point to solve Kepler's Equation

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to solve Kepler's equation ( $ 0 = E - e·\sin(E) + M $ ) with an iterative method but due to the elliptic orbit of the body for some typical values of e and M which causes eccentric anomaly, I prefer to use Secant Method instead of Newton Method. However, I cannot decide on the initial points. For Newton, I use the initial point:
$$ 
E_0=M + \frac{e\sin(M) }{1 - \sin(M + e) + \sin(M)} 
$$

However, what could be a good choice for the second initial point? I guess close values may work but I am not sure.

Comment: $M=E-e\sin E$ is equivalent to $0=E-e\sin(E)-M$, or do you use a different convention? But your initial guess $E_0=M+e\sin M+...$ is compatible with the standard, else one would start with $E_0=-M+...$

Answer (score 1):

*Not using the secant method.*

I always think that it is much better to use Newton method provided that we are able to generate a good starting point. One thing I use to do is to build the $[1,m]$ Padé approximant of  function $f(x)$ around a given point $x_0$.

These approximants write
$$f(x) \sim \frac {f(x_0)+a^{(m)}(x-x_0) } {1+\sum_{i=1}^m b_i^{(m)} (x-x_0)^i}$$ where all coefficients are defined in terms of the function and high-order derivative value at $x_0$. I find this more efficient than series reversion which are often suggested (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation))

Then the estimate
$$x_{(m)}=x_0-\frac {f(x_0)}{a^{(m)}}$$ For small values of $m$, this correspond to Newton method, original Halley method or original Householder method.

For Kepler's equation $$M=E-e \sin(E)$$ using $x_0=0$ this would give the following estimates
$$E_{(0)}=E_{(1)}=\frac M{1-e}$$
$$E_{(2)}=\frac {6(1-e)^2 M} {e M^2+6(1-e)^3}$$
$$E_{(3)}=\frac{e M^3+6 (1-e)^3 M}{2 e (1-e) M^2+6 (1-e)^4}$$

Suppose  $e=0.1$ and $M=0.5678$. Converted to decimals, the above formulae (and the next ones) give

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & E_{(m)} \\
 0 & 0.63088888888888888889 \\
 1 & 0.63088888888888888889 \\
 2 & 0.62627278539121795082 \\
 3 & 0.62630631527966334097 \\
 4 & 0.62642926189145170922 \\
 5 & 0.62642749747544870702 \\
 6 & 0.62642515169269243491 \\
 7 & 0.62642520885980656763 \\
\dots & \cdots \\
\infty & 0.62642525037762133960
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Why E0 depend on E1? Should they be interchanged? Also, I have a specific task that I am required to use Secant, otherwise, I am also comfortable with Newton as I mentioned in the question. Do you think that using your E0 and E1 will work?

Comment: @thisguy. They are not dependent; just equal.

Comment: Oh! my mistake. What about the second question?

Comment: @thisguy. Why not to use a golden search ?

Comment: i do not know what that is and how it will help

Comment: @thisguy.Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search  As soon as the solution has brackets, switch to the secant method.

Comment: As soon as the solution has brackets, what do you mean by this?